# How to find direct parent with specific text using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have requirement where I wanted to find the amount fields like $412,341.40 from document.

I tried `$("div:contains($)").css("background-color","yellow")` but it returning parent div's also, and i just wanted color the child ones.

for e.g see the below image, the above jquery coloring both div's parent and child.[image]

How can i color child div only? I am trying find all div's which contains string like $123,55.60.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Providing some markup and a jsFiddle would improve your chances of getting a correct answer

Comment: You can always use regex to find certain text, http://regexpal.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give your the direct parent.

```
$('div>:contains("$")').last().css("background-color","yellow")
```

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BvdK7/)***

EDIT: The above will work great for only one occurrence of `$`. For multiple occurrences of text, use below code. This makes use `.each()` and looks for a closing `</div>` tag each time.

```
var divs = $('div>:contains("$")');
divs.each(function() {
    var htmlinner = $(this).html();
    if(htmlinner.indexOf('</div>') == -1) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
    }
});
```

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO[2] for multiple occurrences](http://jsfiddle.net/BvdK7/7/)***

Comment: Your answer is perfect, but failing when there are multiple divs contains "$". please check this http://jsfiddle.net/BvdK7/2/

Comment: @sandy - good point. I have modified my code to account multiple occurrences & included it in the answer. Have a look at this demo http://jsfiddle.net/BvdK7/7/

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
$("div:contains('$')").find('div').css("background-color","yellow")
```